# How to receive One signal notifications in flutter

Tags: java, android, dart, flutter, onesignal

I am developing an application with flutter.
There is a feature in my application(Receiving latest news) through One signal notification.

When I add the dependency in my flutter project. It gives me the Error

> (The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version
>   1.2.51 and higher. Project 'flutter_one_signal' is using version 1.1.51)

To remove this error, I have edited the `gradle.build` the file at the location

> (C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_one_signal-0.2.1\android/build.gradle)

But after fixing this dependency conflict. I am now getting another error, which I am not understanding how to remove?

```
e: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_one_signal-0.2.1\android\src\main\kotlin\com\myhexaville\flutteronesignal\FlutterOneSignalPlugin.kt: (50, 35): Type mismatch: inferred type is Boolean? but Boolean was expected
e: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_one_signal-0.2.1\android\src\main\kotlin\com\myhexaville\flutteronesignal\FlutterOneSignalPlugin.kt: (79, 28): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
e: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_one_signal-0.2.1\android\src\main\kotlin\com\myhexaville\flutteronesignal\FlutterOneSignalPlugin.kt: (98, 80): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type String?
```